# an Apt-vs apt-get questiom

Tags: raspbian, apt

I need to learn about the so called 'apt' command, which apparently now replaces the old apt-get.is apt-get depreciated? how do I upgrade a maching still running apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `apt-get` is deprecated you would get a warning when you run it.

`apt` has been available for years.  If you don't have `apt` your operating system is years out of date and you should consider updating.

Comment: In addition: a biit of googling by OP would have resulted in plenty of resources to answer this off-topic query. e.g. https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Comment: as pi uses it in the offical OS< I suggest that asking about a PART of the OS is not off topic. as for googling, I had tried, but was not satisfied with the results.